# Python 3 subprocess.PIPE output error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a simple script that I use to automate CLI calls to our software (the Moab Workload Manager) in testing, to avoid having to use the '--xml' flag to get xml output and then pipe it through tidy so it's easily readable. It uses a `subprocess.Popen` call to run the command, then uses `str.strip()` and `str.replace()` to do a minor cleanup on the returned xml to make it easy to visually inspect. The code in question is here:

---

```
cmdString = "%s --xml" % cmd
cmdList = cmdString.split()

cmdRun = subprocess.Popen(cmdList,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

crOut,crErr = cmdRun.communicate()

xmlOutput = crOut.strip().replace("><",">\n<").replace("\" ","\"\n")
```

---

When I run this (I recently upgraded my Python to Python 3.1.2) I now get the following error:

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/xmlcmd", line 50, in <module>
    runXMLCmd(getCmd())
  File "/usr/local/bin/xmlcmd", line 45, in runXMLCmd
    xmlOutput = crOut.strip().replace("><",">\n<")
TypeError: expected an object with the buffer interface
```

---

It appears that the communicate() call is returning byte arrays, but in the python interpreter, if I do `dir(bytes)` I can still see the strip() and replace() functions. Anybody know how to make this right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bytes.replace()` expects bytes as arguments:

```
crOut.strip().replace(b"><", b">\n<").replace(b"\" ", b"\"\n")
```

Though in general it could be preferable to decode the input to unicode text as early as possible. And the transformations to be performed on the text (not bytes).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `crOut.decode("utf-8")` and do the .replace in the returned string.

Answer (score 1):

In python 3.2, using decode('ascii') fixed some unicode and type errors which were difficult to trace.  Regardless of byte or bytearray the decode will convert to the string as desired.

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen("cmd", 1024, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while pipe.returncode == None:
    lines = pipe.communicate()[0]
    lines = lines.decode('ascii')
    for line in lines.splitlines():
        if (re.search('^---', line)):
            pass # do stuff
```

From the manual,

```
bytes.decode(encoding="utf-8", errors="strict") 
bytearray.decode(encoding="utf-8", errors="strict") 
Return a string decoded from the given bytes. 
Default encoding is 'utf-8'. errors may be given to set a 
different error handling scheme.
```